# after I install a rails gem...I don't see it in /vendor ... where is it?

Tags: rubygems

For only one of my gems, compass, is it showing up in the /vendor subdirectory.

1) Where is it?

2) how do I have it show up in the directory?

Part of the reason is that I need to take a closer look at the gem to see what it is doing because the documentation isn't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install it (using `gem install` or `rake gems:install`) or did you unpack it (using `rake gems:unpack`)?  Unpacking it will put it into your /vendor directory -- installing it will simply put it in the ruby/gems directory.

Comment: aha, perhaps that's it...let me check it out...super, thanks!

Comment: so, I actually used both (!) gem install and rake gems:install when gem install worked....

Comment: hmmm did 'rake gems:unpack' and still not getting the gem which I put into my config and also did a gem install: 'config.gem "postalmethods"'

Comment: Well, for `rake gems:unpack` to work, you need to have the gem referenced in your `environment.rb` file (using `config.gem 'gemname'`).